# How can I change only one of a session object's properties?

Tags: meteor

To set a session variable I must use `Session.set('foo', 'sampletext')`. But what if foo is an object `foo: {bar: 'sample', xyz: 'text'}` and I just want to change `foo.bar`?

Comment: Wild guess: What if you try with Session.set('foo.bar', 'sampletext')?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to work, so either I did something wildly wrong or it doesn't interpret the . operator.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't believe there is a way. That sort of granularity is reserved for collections where you can use Mongo modifiers such as {$set:{bar:'sample'}}. Sessions are not really made with intention of having large objects with complicated structure. If you want to share some code we could likely come up with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Session` doesn't support this. You'd need to replace the whole object:

```js
var foo = Session.get('foo');
foo.bar = 'something';
Session.set('foo', foo);
```

However, `Session` is just an instance of a [ReactiveDict](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/reactive-dict), which does support this:

```js
var fooDict = new ReactiveDict('foo');
fooDict.set('bar', 'something');
```

As long as you name the `ReactiveDict`, it will survive a hot code push and give you the same benefits of `Session`.

Comment: You don't need to stray too far from the tutorial to find out things that aren't too straightforward in meteor. Which kind of bothers me.